# Some icons are missing in the Loxone App after the upgrade of Loxone Config to version 13

Tags: logic, loxone-miniserver

The Status block in the Loxone config does not show icon anymore in the Loxone visualization. The used Loxone Config is version 13.1.10.

Answer (score 0):

Reason is, that version 13.1 of the Loxone app was not finalized (but was fixed in a further alpha version).

So this problem should be gone when the Loxone Config version and Loxone Loxone app is updated to the most actual version. The actual versions can be found on the manufacturer download page (https://www.loxone.com/dede/support/downloads/)